# 2041 distinct natural numbers such that the sum of their squares is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, perfect-squares

Determine if there are 2041 distinct natural numbers such that the sum of
their squares is a perfect square.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Any multiple of $4$ is the difference of two **even** perfect squares.

**Hint 2** You can make the sum of $2040$ perfect squares a multiple of $4$. You can moreover chose the numbers in such a way that they don't repeat and the two numbers in the above hint are not in this set.

Comment: Can you explain it through the numbers and equations because I didn't get how to use these hints
thanks

Comment: Can you please respond

Comment: @NarimanZendehrooh I gave you all the information you need to solve the problem. Pick first 2040 numbers such that the sum of their squares is a multiple of 4. Then make their sum a difference of two squares.